# use recreated fragment stack after restart

Tags: android-fragments

I have an activity with one container displaying a succession of different Fragments. If the activity is recreated because is is returning from background or after an orientation change, the fragments and the backstack are recreatet automatically. I can pop the backstack using the back-button and see actionbuttons changing.

My Problem is: None of the recreated fragments are displayed. How am i supposed to reconnect the backstack with the ContentView?

Im using ActionbarSherlok 4.4.0.
MainActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  if (savedInstanceState == null) {
     PageItem dashboard = new NaviPageItem(R.layout.navi_dashboard);
     dashboard.displayAsRoot(this, R.id.content_frame);
  }
  else {
     // how do i reconnect the recreated fragment stack?
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the error was caused by an old android-support libary. I upgraded to Rev 18 and everything is working as expected.